# How to access to the content: '\E006' of an element?

Tags: html, css

There is a home logo icon in the website. I need to download and use it for the new design. But could not find the source file. It is in the following UTF format.

When I inspect the element, I see the following;

```
.icon_home:before {
content: '\E006';
}
```

How can I get that logo?
What does "E006" mean really  ?
Could not find it in the css files either.

Comment: You need to inspect font-family too.

Comment: may be the font is coming from cdn, like font awesome and the unicode or in this case content to call it in and use it in style

Answer (score 1):

The `\E006` is a character code that is defined in an iconfont file. This file contents icons instead of letters. To show the icon in your page you have to use `@font-face` directive. See [CSS Fonts Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is to import font-family along with your "content" style.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "xxx";
src: url("fonts/awesome-font.woff") format('woff');
}   

.icon_home:before {
content: '\E006';
}

.icon:before, icon:before {
font-family: xxx;
font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here [\e006](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/57350/UTF-8-character) is a UTF-8 character. What happens is, whenever `div` has the class `.icon_home` applied to it, it will append this character before it. This is what it means by the `pseudo-element :before`

```css
.icon_home {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.icon_home:before {
  content: '\E006';
}
```

```html
<div class="icon_home">
</div>
```